# How do I decide between a Wit's End or an Ionic Spark?

Tags: league-of-legends

**Wit's End** gives 40% AS and +42 Magic Damage

**Ionic Spark** gives 50% AS and every fourth attack procs a chain lightning

Several builds for AS focused champions such as Irelia recommend a Wit's End, in her case it also benefits `Bladesurge` which helps with killing fleeing enemies. However, in the general case and if I am trying to adapt my equipment to the situation (and I have an AS focused champ) - how to decide between them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Wits End also gives you some magic resist (+30 base, upto +50 total) and costs 2150 total
- Ionic Spark gives +250 health and costs 2100 total.

The average extra damage-per-hit is approximately the same, so we'll ignore it as well as the 50 gold difference in building.

So the things that you need to consider are as follows:

- what is more useful? 50 MR or 250 HP?
- early on, do I prefer a Ruby Crystal or a Null-Magic Mantle?

Comment: So its situational based on enemy AP champs? I was wondering if dmg is similar, why more people don't suggest Ionic Spark for extra 10% AS

Comment: Most builds should not even consider either item; PD is by far better, and stackable.

Comment: PD is too expensive for non-carry ADs. Wit's end is better for tanks who are afraid of AP damage, and ionic spark is generally seen as a better farming item.
But either way, you have to make the decision of whether you need to be tankier for team fights or if you need to do more damage/have a better farming item. Shen for instance can definitely use ionic spark to help him split push